# Help proving that the sum of consecutive integers raised to the same power is upper bounded by a monomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, asymptotics

I want to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n{i^k}=O(n^{k+1})$ for all integers $k\geq1$. I'm attempting to prove this using mathematical induction over $n$. Here's what I've got:

For the base case, let $n=1$. We want to prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^1{i^k}\leq cn^{k+1}$. Thus, we have that:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^1{i^k}=1^k=1\leq{c}=c(1)^{k+1},
$$
which is true for any value for $k$ so long as $c\geq{1}$.

Now, suppose that $\sum_{i=1}^n{i^k}\leq cn^{k+1}$ for any integer $n$. We're now attempting to prove that such assumption implies that $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{i^k}\leq c(n+1)^{k+1}$. So, we have that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{i^k}&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^k}+(n+1)^k\\
&\leq cn^{k+1}+(n+1)^k\\
&=c(n+1)^{k+1}\left[\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{k+1}+\dfrac{1}{c(n+1)}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
~~

And this is as far as I've got in the proof. I'm not really sure how I should continue this proof. I think the last relation is true as long as I can show that
$$
(1)\qquad\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{k+1}+\dfrac{1}{c(n+1)}\geq1.
$$

As far as my understanding goes, from here I should attempt to come up with a constant lower bound for $c$. However if I do algebra on (1), all I can come up with is with a bound for $c$ *that depends on* $n$; that is, $c$ wouldn't be a *constant*.

So my questions are the following:

1. Is mathematical induction the appropiate approach for proving $\sum_{i=1}^n{i^k}=O(n^{k+1})$?
2. If so, where did my proof went wrong? What corrections should I do in order to complete it?
3. If not, what is a better approach?

Any corrections, hints or explanation will be appreciated.

EDIT: corrected some algebra and clarified what my questions were.

Answer (score 3):

Surely the simplest way is

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n i^k \le \sum_{i=1}^n n^k = n^{k+1} $$